# XSLT | Group XSLT using identifier | Add all the element in that group

Tags: xslt

I have to group fields on an identifier and add the values on the basis of identifier.
I tied group-by in XSLT 2.0, this is able to group the fields, however I also want to to add the quantity element inside the group.

Input XML:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        <Description>01_PROPER</Description>
        <Quantity>100.000000</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>01_PROPER</Description>
        <Quantity>100.000000</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>01_PROPER</Description>
        <Quantity>100.000000</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>02_PROPER</Description>
        <Quantity>100.000000</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>02_PROPER</Description>
        <Quantity>100.000000</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>03_PROPER</Description>
        <Quantity>100.000000</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>04_PROPER</Description>
        <Quantity>100.000000</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>04_PROPER</Description>
        <Quantity>100.000000</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>04_PROPER</Description>
        <Quantity>100.000000</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>05_PROPER</Description>
        <Quantity>100.000000</Quantity>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

Output XML:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        <Description>01_PROPER</Description>
        <Quantity>300.000000</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>02_PROPER</Description>
        <Quantity>200.000000</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>03_PROPER</Description>
        <Quantity>100.000000</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>04_PROPER</Description>
        <Quantity>300.000000</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>05_PROPER</Description>
        <Quantity>100.000000</Quantity>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

I tried below XSLT 2.0 but not working as expected.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Items>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="/Items/Item" group-by="Description">
          <Item>
            <Description>
              <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
            </Description>
            <Quantity>
              <xsl:value-of select="(Quantity)"/>
            </Quantity>
          </Item>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Items>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks
Yatan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<Quantity>
    <xsl:value-of select="(Quantity)"/>
</Quantity>
```

do:

```
<Quantity>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Quantity)"/>
</Quantity>
```

or, if you prefer:

```
<Quantity>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/Quantity), '0.000000')"/>
</Quantity>
```